# Java, how to deactivate daylight saving?

Tags: java, date, dst

Egypt has no more daylight saving, I'm making a web app in a server, and trying to change the time to Egypt time, it worked, but with daylight saving mode, how can I deactivate it!!

Comment: DST has just added more work for us. Especially when you're dealing with reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't turn off daylight savings in the JVM.  Each timezone is encoded with an offset and whether or not daylight savings time is applied (and if so, between what dates).

You can check this with:

```
TimeZone.getDefault().useDaylightTime();
TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime( new Date() );
```

However, you can update your timezone files in your JDK installation with the TZUpdater tool:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html

PS:  Here's the revision of the timezone file where the change for egypt was introduced.  There have since been 10 additional updates.

Version         JRE Versions Introduced   TzUpdaterVersion  Description

tzdata2011g  1.4.2_33  5.0u31 6u26 7      1.3.39                   Change of DST rules for Egypt to abandon DST this year.

Comment: Yes, and the only way to correct that is to update the timezone file with the link i provided.

Comment: The right way is to update your java version. Whenever daylight savings info changes for a locale, there's usually an immediate java release that patches the locale data

Answer (score 2):

Related with Matt's answer, with a Java 1.6.0_31:

```
Date now = new Date();

TimeZone zoneEET = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET"); // Traditionally used for Egypt
System.out.println(zoneEET.getDSTSavings());  // 1h for DST
System.out.println(zoneEET.getRawOffset());  // GMT+2
System.out.println(zoneEET.inDaylightTime(now)); // true
TimeZone.setDefault(zoneEET));
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println("");

TimeZone zoneEgypt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Egypt"));
System.out.println(zoneEgypt.getDSTSavings()); // no DST
System.out.println(zoneEgypt.getRawOffset()); // GMT+2
System.out.println(zoneEgypt.inDaylightTime(now)); // false
TimeZone.setDefault(zoneEgypt));
System.out.println(now);
```

So it seems that from 1.6.0_26 there is a "special" zone named "Egypt" with no DST.

Comment: it works "locally", I don't know why in the server it isn't give me the right time!!!

Comment: What do you get in the server when running `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`?

Comment: In fact, you can use the `"GMT"` TimeZone to remove the DayLight saving for any JVM. I`ve tested on 1.4, 1.6 and 17.
```TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in an antiquated and restricted setting where upgrading the tz database in Java is not possible, to "deactivate" the DST, you can configure the GMT timezone as your default timezone. You can configure in the JVM arguments

```java
 -Duser.timezone="GMT"
```

Or by conding

```java
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Here a code for old Java versions (Java 7 and before) that checks the correctness of this solution.
https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/VzO

```java
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class CheckDSTRemove {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        core();
    }
    private static void core() {
        boolean isSafe = true;
        for (int year = 1900; year <= 2100; year++) { //Some Years of interest
            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
                int maxDay;
                switch (month) {
                case 1: //To run in any JVM
                case 3: 
                case 5: 
                case 7: 
                case 8: 
                case 12: {
                    maxDay = 31;
                    break;
                }
                case 4: 
                case 6: 
                case 9: 
                case 11: {
                    maxDay = 30;
                    break;
                }
                default://Feb
                    maxDay = 28;
                    if(year%4==0 && year%100 != 0 ) { //I've missing the 400 years rule
                        maxDay = 29;
                    }
                }
                for (int dia = 1; dia <= maxDay; dia++) {
                    String s = oldSchoolDayFormat(year, month, dia)+"000000";//To check the border time

                    Date d = toDate(s);
                    java.sql.Timestamp t = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
                    String strHour = (t+"").substring(11, 13);
                    if(!"00".equals(strHour)) {// If in the first day of Dayligth saving, this number will be 01
                        System.out.println(s);
                        isSafe = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if(isSafe) {
            System.out.println("Success!!!");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Old School format that run in any JVM
     * @param year
     * @param month
     * @param day
     * @return
     */
    private static String oldSchoolDayFormat(int year, int month, int day) {
        String strMonth = (month<10?"0"+month:""+month);
        String strDay = (day<10?"0"+day:""+day);
        return year + strMonth + strDay;
    }

    private static Date toDate(String strDate) {
        Date result = null;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try {
            result = format.parse(strDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. The correct solution to the OP’s problem was updating the time-zone database in Java. The default time zone should not matter since your date and time operations should be independent of it. I can’t read your code. You should never ever use the *old school* `Date`, `Timestamp` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes, they had severe design problems are have been outdated for 10 years.

Comment: Your code does not work. Europe/Paris time zone uses summer time (DST). I changed the first line of your main method to `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));`, and your program still printed *Success!!!*.

Comment: The proposed solution, which involved altering the Time Zone to GMT, was solely focused on a code-centric approach. Within large-scale companies, developers typically lack elevated user privileges (i.e., root access) to modify the tzdb. Therefore, utilizing "Egypt" as an alternative is deemed a inferior solution. The verification code was intentionally crafted using traditional classes, as this approach catered to older JVM environments.

Comment: The approach of using GMT instead does not work for the OP’s problem either since Egypt uses summer time (DST) again since 2023. Also the way I understood the question, the OP still wants to convert time to Egypt time, not to GMT.

Comment: About the test on "Europe/Paris", the check code doesn't work because Paris change the hour at 2AM. I've changed the code to add this particularity. https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/VB0

Comment: The utilization of GMT offers a viable solution to the primary inquiry: "Java, how to deactivate daylight saving??" While I acknowledge the merit of updating the tzdb, in highly restricted and antiquated environments, a code-centric solution presents a more refined approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256808/discussion-between-magnocorrea-and-anonymous).

Comment: Yes I have [continued the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256808/discussion-between-magnocorrea-and-anonymous).